# Can we play Audio file from app files path?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-player, android-music-player, android-fileprovider

I'm developing the mp3 music player application. I want in my application to play the audio file, when user try to play audio file from other apps.

When user try to play audio file from **Xender** app, it will be open with app dialog . From this dialog user will be select my app and app will be ready to play selected songs.

I'm trying to play song in Latest version Android Pie. I got the file path url but **Android MediaPlayer** can't play audio with below path.

> /data/user/0/com.mp3musicapp/files/mumbai dilli di kudiyaan - songs.pk - 320kbps.mp3

So, please any one help me out for this issue. I'm trying from last 2 days, but till now not getting any solution. So Please help me for this issue. How do I solve this?

**App Code:**

```
Intent returnIntent = getIntent(); 
Uri returnUri = returnIntent.getData(); 
String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(returnUri);

if (mimeType != null) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    if (filePathHelper.getPathnew(returnUri, getApplicationContext()) != null) {

                        audioRealPath = filePathHelper.getPathnew(returnUri, getApplicationContext()).toLowerCase();
                    } else {
                        audioRealPath = filePathHelper.getFilePathFromURI(returnUri, getApplicationContext()).toLowerCase();
                    }
                } else {
                    audioRealPath = filePathHelper.getPath(returnUri, getApplicationContext()).toLowerCase();
                }
            }

 Uri tempAudioUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(audioRealPath));


                File filePath = new File(tempAudioUri.toString());
                if (!filePath.exists()) {
                    filePath.createNewFile();
                }
                FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);


                MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                try {
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(is.getFD());
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Please add relevant code.

Comment: okay @SahilManchanda